# How to view the data from server using $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an empty array called `$scope.mobileBrandArray= [];`

Now I am trying to get the data from my server using `$http.get()` inside the function.

Here is my `app.js` code

```
app.controller('myCtrl' , function($scope , $http){
    $scope.mobileBrandArray = [];   
    $scope.getMobileBrandArray = function(){
      $http.get("http://192.168.101.4:9090/Mobile_ERP/rest/brand/")
        .success(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
         console.log(response[0].brandKey);
          $scope.mobileBrandArray=response;
          console.log($scope.mobileBrandArray);
        })
        .error(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          alert("error ");
        })
    }; 
});
```

Here I am not able to view my data in the UI, but I try `$http.get()` function without the `$scope.getMobileBrandArray();` it works fine but i need my array outside the `$scope.getMobileBrandArray();`

Here is my `HTML`code

```
<tr ng-repeat="mobileBrand in mobileBrandArray" ng-include="getTemplate(mobileBrand)">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
        <td>{{mobileBrand.brandCode}}</td>
        <td>{{mobileBrand.brandName}}</td>
        <td>{{mobileBrand.brandStatus}}</td>
        <td>{{mobileBrand.brandCreatedOn}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editMobileData(mobileBrand)">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteMobileData(mobileBrand)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
        <td><input type="text" ng-model=mobileBrand.brandCode class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model=mobileBrand.brandName class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model=mobileBrand.brandStatus class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model=mobileBrand.brandCreatedOn class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateMobileData(mobileBrand)">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </script>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you show your view template?

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: show the getTemplate() method

Comment: $scope.getTemplate = function (mobileBrand) {
        if (mobileBrand.brandKey === $scope.selected.brandKey){
   console.log(mobileBrand.brandKey);
   console.log($scope.selected.brandKey);
   return 'edit';
  }
        else { 
   console.log(mobileBrand.brandKey);
   console.log($scope.selected.brandKey);
   return 'display';
   }
    };

Comment: have you called $scope.getMobileBrandArray(); in your controller ??

Comment: yes when i click save button i need to call the getMobileBrandArray();

Comment: then try declaring $scope.mobileBrand = {brandCode:'',brandName:'',brandStatus:'',brandCreatedOn:''};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you call the `getMobileBrandArray()` function. You have two options you could:

add `ng-init='getMobileBrandArray()'` to the top of your table to automatically run the `$http.get` function.

or add `ng-click='getMobileBrandArray()'` to a button you want to initiate the get function.